# How can I replace a string inside a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, recursion, replace

How can I replace a string/word that's inside a multidimensional array with a new value? I don't have its key, just know the haystack and the needle.

Say I have a multidimensional array, `$submenu_arr`, (don't know how many dimensions).

I want to find a value inside one of these arrays and replace it with a new value.

Actually for a translation.

Like:

```
 recursive_arr_translation('Article', $submenu_arr, 'Artigo');//"Artigo" is a Portuguese word for "Article".
```

I've tried this, but not working:

```
 function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $new_value) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        if ($value === $needle) { 
                $found = true; 
                $haystack[$key] = $new_value;
                return true;
            } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                $found = in_array_r($needle, $haystack[$key], $new_value); 
                if($found) { 
                    return true; 
                } 
            }    
        }
        return $found;
    }


in_array_r('Article', $submenu, 'Artigo');
in_array_r('Location', $submenu, 'Localização');
```

EDIT: Is working, but somehow, I don't get it working, I'm trying to translate a WordPress submenu word.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive`...?!

Comment: array_walk_recursive new to me

Comment: http://php.net/array_walk_recursive

Comment: @deceze could you give me an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**`array_walk_recursive`**](https://www.php.net/array_walk_recursive) as suggested in the comments, and pass your original array as reference, allowing us to edit it.

```
<?php

$a = array("Giraffe", "Monkey", "Elephant", "Snake", 5, "other" => array("apple", "orange"));

array_walk_recursive($a, function(&$a) {
        if($a == "apple") {
             $a = "Banana";
        }
});

echo print_r($a, true);
```

https://eval.in/198978

So, now we have the basic logic, let's create a function with 3 parameters.

```
function replace_in_array($find, $replace, &$array) {
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$array) use($find, $replace) {
        if($array == $find) {
             $array= $replace;
        }
    });
    return $array;
}

$a = array("Giraffe", "Monkey", "Elephant", "Snake", 5, "other" => array("apple", "orange"));
echo print_r( replace_in_array("apple", "banana", $a), true);
```

https://eval.in/198989

Comment: Currently the if ($array == $find) will also replace any value of 1 as it will see it as true. If you wish to make it identical use ===  instead of ==.